# Using sqlite how can i update or insert to a table using a condition?

Tags: sqlite

Having a blank table with three columns

```
CREATE TABLE AssyData    ( AID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE , MaxDef float  , MaxDefLC int  , MaxDefNID int , Comps text , SubAssys text )
```

I would like to Update or insert new values if the new MaxMag is larger than the current one and if the AID is the same. AID is a unique Primary key. Assuming an AID of 100 I have tried the following, but with no success:

```
INSERT INTO AssyData 
(AID  , MaxDef  , MaxDefLC  , MaxDefNID , Comps  , SubAssys) 
VALUES( 100 , 101 , 202 , 203 , "" , "") 
ON CONFLICT(AID) 
DO UPDATE 
SET 
MaxDef = excluded.MaxDef , 
MaxDefNID = excluded.MaxDefNID ,
MaxDefLC = excluded.MaxDefLC ,
Comps = excluded.Comps ,
SubAssys = excluded.SubAssys
WHERE excluded.MaxDef > 100
```

I get the error "near "ON": syntax error"

What is wrong with my statement?

Thanks Shawn for the Approach.

Comment: Check your SQLite version. Is it 3.24.0+? If not then you can't use UPSERT.

Comment: I only have sqlite 3.7.16.1, that is the reason for the error. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your vesrsion of SQLite does not allow the use of `UPSERT` you can achieve what you need in 2 steps:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO AssyData 
(AID, MaxDef, MaxDefLC, MaxDefNID, Comps, SubAssys) 
VALUES(100, 111, 202, 203, '', '');
```

This `INSERT OR IGNORE` will fail without an error if you try to insert a row with an `AID` that already exists in the table.
Then:

```
UPDATE AssyData
SET 
  MaxDef = 111, 
  MaxDefLC = 202,
  MaxDefNID = 203,
  Comps = '',
  SubAssys = ''
WHERE AID = 100 AND MaxDef < 111;
```

This will fail if the row to be updated contains `MaxDef` equal or greater than the value `111`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7rYbwZmf5rcH8NpbxG15cz/2).
In general such code needs special care when implemented, because as you can see the value  of `MaxDef` (`111` in this example) must be set 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a somewhat recent (3.24 or newer) version of sqlite, you can use what's known as [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
INSERT INTO AssyData(AID, MaxMag, MaxDefNID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(AID) DO UPDATE SET MaxMag = excluded.MaxMag
                             , MaxDefNID = excluded.MaxDefNID
                    WHERE excluded.MaxMag > MaxMag;
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn, but I only have Access to sqlite 3.7.16.1 ...